# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' when installing TRT_pose

Tags: python, torch, ubuntu-20.04, torchvision, torchaudio

I am trying to get started using [TRT_pose](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/trt_pose), but I am stuck when trying to install plugins from `setup.py`, using this line in terminal: `sudo python3 setup.py install --plugins`. I get the error

```
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

But I have already installed torch, torchvision, and torchaudio with `pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cpu torchvision==0.10.0+cpu torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`, so I do not know why I am still seeing this error. I am running Ubuntu 20.4 on Virtual Machine, and have Python 3.8.5 installed on it.

Comment: Does torch show up in the list if you run `pip3 list` ? (can get confusing if you're using virtual enviroments and you've accidentally activated one that doesn't have torch installed)

Comment: Yes, this is what shows up:
```torch 1.9.0+cpu
torchaudio  0.9.0
torchvision  0.10.0+cpu```

Comment: And you're launching python3, not python ? (just in case python is version 2 for some reason ?) e.g. what's the output of python3 -c "import torch;print(torch.__version__)" ?

Comment: Yes, I am using python3 in the setup line, and the output is `1.9.0+cpu`

Comment: It does sound like you're doing everything correctly. Hopefully others have suggestions on potential curveballs to avoid. Silly question, but have you tried rebooting and trying again, just in case some native paths aren't fully set up properly yet ? if `1.9.0+cpu` is what python3 is output, clearly it imported pytorch correctly, so it's very strange that setup.py doesn't see it. (could it be user / permissions issue ? Does `sudo python3 -c "import torch;print(torch.__version__)"` also print the version ? (if not you might need to sudo pip3 install pytorch...)

Comment: It did not, I just installed torch, torchvision and torchaudio on sudo now. I just ran the line again for setup.py, and got ```OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root```. Do I need to install CUDA?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234089/discussion-between-george-profenza-and-john-adams).

Answer (score 0):

Please take my advise with a pinch of salt: I haven't ran trt_pose yet.

It sounds like the issues are related to what's installed as your default user versus the super user.

The fact that `python3 -c "import torch;print(torch.__version__)"` outputs `1.9.0+cpu`, yet `sudo python3 setup.py install --plugins` crashes on importing pytorch points to the fact the PyTorch is installed for your user, but not superuser.

You have multiple options, some simpler than others:

1. Do you need to use `sudo` ? If you already have dependencies (PyTorch, CUDA, etc.) installed for your user, maybe you can follow the install guide without prefixing the commands with `sudo`
2. If you do need to use sudo one option is to reinstall dependencies your current user already has installed, but as `sudo`
3. A potentially hacky workaround for the above is to make symbolic links from your user to the `sudo` user paths so the same libraries/binaries and pip3 packages your users has installed are also available for `sudo`

Since `trt_pose` is meant to run on nVidia hardware it's worth double checking if it's the cpu version of PyTorch you need to use or the gpu + cuda one instead.